# How to extract message in Bleichenbacher 1998 attack

Tags: rsa, padding-oracle

I'm trying to understand the Bleichenbacher 1998 attack, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around the bounds-part.

So as far as I understand, the idea is the following:

We have a ciphertext $c = m^e \bmod n$ and we are trying to find the message $m$. So we want to make use of the fact that: $s^e \cdot c \bmod n = s^{e} \times m^e \bmod n = (s \times m)^e \bmod n$, which decrypts to $m \cdot s$. Say our new modified ciphertext $c'$ decrypts to $ms$, knowing $s$, we can then extract $m$ by calculating $m = ms \cdot s^{-1}$.

So we try out a bunch of different $s$ until we find one so that $ms$ is PKCS compliant. Now we know that $ms$ starts with `00 02`, but it doesn't tell us anything about the rest of the decrypted message.

I do not really understand the concept of trying different bounds and ranges and how we can obtain the whole $ms$ message from it and thus extract $m$.

Can someone please explain to me the concept of how we gain more information on $ms$ by modifying $s$ ?

Comment: For me the [improved attack from Crypto 2012](https://ia.cr/2012/417) was easier to understand than the original. There is also a [tutorial](https://www.dsi.unive.it/~focardi/RSA-padding-oracle) by one of the authors. See also the answer to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/78254/142).

Comment: Thanks alot, i will look into that one!